# Watching ngModel of an element from attribute directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want to watch a model from inside a directive that I place as an attribute on an `input` element:

```
<input id="mymodel_headline" name="mymodel[headline]" 
      ng-model="mymodel.headline" sps-watch="true" type="text">
```

If I'm reading the docs right I should be able to get the value either through the link function's `attrs` parameter, or from requiring `ngModel`. However, neither of these approaches are working:

```
app.directive('spsWatch', function() {
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      console.log("directive called");
      console.log(attrs.ngModel);

      scope.$watch(scope[attrs.ngModel], function(result) {
        console.log("watching via attribute");
        console.log(result);
      });

      scope.$watch(ngModel, function(result) {
        console.log("watching via ngModel");
        console.log(result)
      });          
    }
  };      
});
```

They seem to run once only, when the directive is first created.

[Plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/DFXDmTWqLFz21SYqpnow?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the value of your model via `ngModel.$viewValue`. Return that from an anonymous function in your `$watch` expression, and changes in the model will trigger your `$watch` function:

```
  scope.$watch(function () {
    return ngModel.$viewValue;
  }, function(result) {
    console.log("watching via ngModel");
    console.log(result)
  });
```

Comment: Interesting, why is it necessary to wrap the first argument in an anonymous function?

Comment: the expression for `$watch` may be either a function or a string. In the first case it registers changes in the return value, in the latter case it interpretes the string as an angular expression. It is not possible to just specify a variable that should be watched.